# Mapping array of arguments into tuples of <T extends Tuple> = [T, (...args: NonNullArray<T>) => any] where each tuple is the argument of a function

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, unions

To explain what I want to achieve I will start with the most basic piece of the puzzle: a function whose first argument is a tuple and the second argument is a function whose arguments are the (non-nulled) elements of the tuple:

```
let first: number | null | undefined;
let last: number | null | undefined;
let before: Date | null | undefined;
let after: Date | null | undefined;

function iff<T extends any[]>(...arr: [T, (...args: NonNullableArray<T>) => any]): void {}

iff([first, last], (first, last) => null); // (first, last) is (number, number)
```

So far so good. Now I want to achieve the same but the function has to accept an array of arguments where each one of them meets the signature of the precedent function (I'm dropping the non-nullable part for simplicity).

```
function multipleIfs<
  A extends any[] & {
    [k in ArrayKeys<A>]: [A[k][0], (args: A[k][0]) => any];
  }
>(arg: A): void {}

multipleIfs([
  [[first, last], ([first, last]) => null], // (first, last) is (any, any)
  [[after, before], ([after, before]) => null], // (after, before) is (any, any)
]);
multipleIfs([ // OK
  [[first, last], (arg: [typeof first, typeof last]) => null],
  [[after, before], (arg: [typeof after, typeof before]) => null],
]);
multipleIfs([ // FORBIDDEN
  [[first, last], (arg: [typeof after, typeof before]) => null],
  [[after, before], (arg: [typeof after, typeof before]) => null],
]);
multipleIfs([ // OK ???
  [[first, last], (arg: [typeof after, typeof before]) => null],
  [[after, before], (arg: [typeof first, typeof before]) => null],
]);
multipleIfs<A>([ // We have to hint the type because it won't infer it
  [[first, last], ([first, last]) => null],
  [[after, before], ([after, before]) => null],
]);
```

It mostly doesn't work because while it forbids some non matching arguments it doesn't always do so and it won't infer the argument type for the function from the tuple.

I couldn't implement it programmatically for an array of arbitrary size, but up to a certain size I could do the following:

```
type IffArgs<T extends Tuple> = [T, (...args: NonNullableArray<T>) => any];
function multipleIfs3<
  T0 extends Tuple,
  T1 extends Tuple,
  T2 extends Tuple,
  T3 extends Tuple,
  T4 extends Tuple,
  T5 extends Tuple,
  T6 extends Tuple,
  T7 extends Tuple,
  T8 extends Tuple,
  T9 extends Tuple
>(
  ...arr: [
    IffArgs<T0>,
    IffArgs<T1>?,
    IffArgs<T2>?,
    IffArgs<T3>?,
    IffArgs<T4>?,
    IffArgs<T5>?,
    IffArgs<T6>?,
    IffArgs<T7>?,
    IffArgs<T8>?,
    IffArgs<T9>?,
    never?
  ]
): void {}
multipleIfs3([[first, last], (first, last) => null], [[after, before], (after, before) => null]); // OK
```

Here is [the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAPDKBeKBDAdiAPkygG0YAaKAOhphIF16BuAKFEigEEAnb7EANIQQAZzRQIAD2ARcAExFRuEbHID2uRCBz4GRLAFFpfAMbAUAa2FqAZrEoADACQBvXHAC2AIwjcAvg5EUjLyis4uAJa4Nr5QAHIS0rIKUO7evgEsUFAA-PGJISlWILawWdm58eXZAFypEABuvuV1uI2%20rOzQcRpxcIiI2F7IPHwg4sHJinggesQupBFQUVDFpTD0dT24fQNDyGgkEfREfqwsyMBQNhHcIsCtnj7cUAA%20qf2Ib1Bw8hA3bTkrEuUEG90e6Re73cA2%20vzk-yiECBFwgVx8NjUyjqABFsDJvjCvu94YjAcC0TgbDJuLj8dBoZ84X8AcjzjZfmYIhpljYbBMkqEdLMTgAKGhUbC8OpkSjimhSgDmIi2vU%20%20wgo34aAIAEpMEQZvRdXUGmoInIoC4-CwInzRSQbndgJQwcB6HKnfdXdh7vqMEQibqmFAAPShqCir0u0G%204D6iKKUVpZ6UFO%20XUsFgc3BcnkefrACJICAASRsYnKnAKU2FDCgADIrdVSBZlrguLx%20EJRChOARNqROCQLPQSAAGD2RpUqrgjseT-2G-DMco2giipV1TgmqBmi1Wm1dLjEEjlM8VUjpqEfWEkllIuRpp6xRl3n4PwEelub7iKmXXoSTL3girJPh8kJAe%20pJgcaBrCuU37ZBeFQkHiBJvsSH6gY%20lDoQyt5YTBj5IRUv7-qQ%20FQURn7Inh9LUcyOFfkuCHZPQLCriYGj3FAMj3AAjHULjnm2KxaoIwhiP2g4kMOo4TlO5GztsuyDMMmpduM8kLicrFGqwfinuejq3N6sb3EppnOj6lmsUSU7hpG0a2fGyxJtez6QpmyEkNg1K%20JQGJYhAVn%20TSQX-CFcEBoRjkRpuAXcJFmLKAmSb4fRMiZquBaIEWJbliIDomS5FnunK1nmW6MWBp88XOWZMZuul074JQMw%20aQflJSl0WVeFgVQMFyi1XFlBOYlEXDVFaXuW1IAdfgOXBiweUFcgRUOmGEYAPICKVTWuUpW6kF0pRleddg1fZ9XkCZg3JTNqWhXKp0kFdVLTZ9I2hbdAzfsarDrcWm0VttTkAGK7QASgAQqWOI4gYcSHTZ5UnX%20MqfY9lA-bNf3wQ592%20bjz39dOWNneAEClGT%20MvWNxOcatIOFeDJA7VA%2025DkORo9VcaYxRH003TvV8WLdi-Uzd0PRLMtvVTouQBdR2S6r0sE7LAP3UDa2FqDZYVn2G6c05ADq0AABbYE0fFqFA1tRFcwDW9Ax4%20CY2BwCI0ARFcADuGgAORXFEMQvAHAvNULlVlTdRNy6TCvawNqeM-9iCA6t2ackW%20aG%20zIgAExoAgyC2PAJY1kKMwMHov60s2l4ju2nZjD2YjV5XNg9xAA51P3VcVxA861yk9ccZeeRkKPI8lvOcoSjOqo7OqGkSeXJYL8g856vBRotq07TcIZu77pa1psDTUAALIgP3ihYChyGAZhTFknREHPIxIFf3IUiyEqIf3-mBLKBEiSf1gpxVg3FcC8X4sAEuwkWxt3ElpLuKAH5P0HvfR%20o8RDj0mHXXQ08KizxwYQpekYV5-hUmqPYm8tLYIISWIho4D6xSPpeE%20TQz4sCMi-NBVVY6WU9OrFqSddZcyjJIuMrVkwvieteLqKdpqK2nBnEKWcGpTSGr9RRmUoD4RysDIuYNS4lVbqI46Ej0ZSNisTWRCcFHzU3O1YUajupk00fop6hjpHZwmglXxBNFEzCWiAFa5j8pGyKmXKh7CzZcytk7O2HtHbO1wK7d2GtoBex9n7ZYQdQ7h2iLEaONjXHiMag4txTjk6oR6hotOWjWkvV0XrXOx5yw2B4MqAUhRFD930KQCgtCFT0LXmpDUW8YBcOXCAVcOY8wdjZpYgAzCgcoMBxwTxGaPEmsABIHNgEc3ZJczn92OTATZ1yLnZBgAAFgeSWW5ABWN5yBbkADZvkQFuQAdgBbcgAHKC3ZABOAFLANzlDoc3V%20UA%20kDO7uOAgxzsiovoWgASBAchYpRXyNFaAS4EqJTiwZdyKUtipd3Z5tLLz0rQB8plFQWUwF%20ey7FJLcUwCBTy4l-T%20VgqFZyqFQq2j8P5uxFgF9zRXxtBs42IhNkOlsRjexgs-RBKnCQFpBi2n%20L6nNRpANgxc32kAA).

I don't like the latter approach, but I couldn't device anything better.
Any ideas on how to improve it?

Comment: Why are you writing `([first, last]) => null` instead of `(first, last) => null`?  Do you really want a *single tuple-typed* argument?  I assume those are mistakes?

Comment: I'd say this is an inference problem described at [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599); the second element of each tuple is a context-sensitive callback and it depends on having the first element inferred first, but context-sensitive callbacks tend to have their inference *delayed* and it's too late. ...

Comment: ... There have been steady improvements to such inference but there are still (and will always be) cases where inference fails.  Would you be interested in refactoring to, say, something more like `diffIffs([[x, y], [t, u]], [(x, y)=>{}, (t, u)=>{}])` where the callbacks are all together and after the inputs?  If so I could look into it; if not I might write up a "sorry this probably is impossible currently" answer.  Let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: I'm writing ([first, last]) to avoid putting a spreading operator in (...args: A[k][0]) which simplifies things a little bit. Otherwise in some of the crazier tentative implementations I tried I had to enforce it to extend any[] or it complained about the spread.

Comment: This is part of a wider utility type to conditionally write complex sql queries. It has many overloads like:
`(tuple of variables, (non-null variables) => SqlFragment)` or `(additional conditions, tuple of variables, (non-null variables) => SqlFragment))` or `(conditions, SqlFragment)`

We are discussing the array version of the first overload where you also specify a fragment (like WHERE) and a glue (like AND), which is used for things like `WHERE [conditional fragment] AND [conditional fragment]` so it is important to keep things together or it becomes hard to read. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think there's any better way to get inference for the function call as written and I can write up an answer outlining the general limitations here.  But I'd say if you find yourself doing this then you should refactor to work with the type system instead of against it (assuming you have the ability to refactor and this isn't some existing js you're trying to give types to)... for example, you could use a fluent builder pattern [as shown here](//tsplay.dev/WJVR6W), where method chaining replaces long arrays. Would you like to see that in an answer or just "no, sorry and here's why"?

Comment: It is indeed an existing codebase, but I have good test coverage and I am already refactoring the hell out of it so the fluent builder pattern looks like an interesting option. At this point I am basically writing my own query builder (which is exactly what I wanted to avoid) but it could actually be a better solution all things considered: I can still hand write the bulk of the SQL query and add a few sprinkles of the custom query builder whenever it makes the query more easily readable.

Comment: So if I write up an answer describing what's happening in TS and suggesting the builder pattern as a possible workaround, would you be likely to accept it?  Or am I missing something about the question?  I'd like to move the info here out of comments and into an answer unless I'm missing something about the situation.

Comment: Of course, you've already been of tremendous help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a limitation of TypeScript.

TypeScript's inference algorithm works well in a wide range of real-world use cases, but it is far from perfect.  One broad limitation is that it cannot always simultaneously infer [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments and also infer parameter types of [context-sensitive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) functions (i.e., those with unannotated parameters like `x => x + 1` as opposed to `(x: number) => x + 1`).  Inference occurs in some finite number of "passes", and sometimes these will be exhausted before some types are inferred.

There has been steady improvement here, such as [TS4.7's added support for such inference in objects and methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods), but there are still failures.  In the absence of a full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) algorithm as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), there will always be situations where the compiler will fail to infer types.

Your `multipleIfs` function with ten generic type parameters (`T0`,`T1`, ⋯, `T9`) works because the compiler can infer each type argument separately and then each callback parameter from it.  But if you try to refactor to use a single type parameter which acts as a [mapped tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) of type parameters (e.g., `type T = [T0, T1, ⋯, T9]`) like so:

```
declare function multipleIfs<T extends readonly (readonly any[])[]>(
  args: readonly [...{ [I in keyof T]: readonly [
    args: readonly [...T[I]],
    cb: (...args: NonNullableArray<T[I]>) => unknown
  ] }]
): OutputType<T>
```

Then contextual inference will fail even though the type argument is inferred correctly:

```
const result = multipleIfs([
  [[first, last], (first, last) => null],
  //               ~~~~~  ~~~~ implicit any ☹
  [[after, before], (after, before) => null]
  //                 ~~~~~  ~~~~~~ implicit any ☹
]);
/* const result: OutputType<[
     [number | null | undefined, number | null | undefined], 
     [Date | null | undefined, Date | null | undefined]
]> */
```

And that's because in order for this to work the compiler would either have to infer `T` "in pieces", or else perform a bunch of contextual typing passes after `T` is inferred, neither of which is currently supported.

---

Maybe someday the inference algorithm will be improved to handle cases like this.  But until and unless this happens, my suggestion is to refactor where possible to work *with* TypeScript's inference algorithm instead of *against* it.  One approach is to replace your array with a [fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), so instead of `foo([x, y, z])` you write something like `foo(x).and(y).and(z).done()`. This lets you make something that works for arbitrary numbers of arguments and where each method call gives you a new chance for inference to work.

For `multipleIfs` it could look like this:

```
interface MultipleIfs<T extends readonly (readonly any[])[]> {
  and<U extends readonly any[]>(
    args: readonly [...U],
    cb: (...args: NonNullableArray<U>) => unknown
  ): MultipleIfs<[...T, U]>;
  done(): OutputType<T>;
}

declare function multipleIfs<U extends readonly any[]>(
  args: readonly [...U],
  cb: (...args: NonNullableArray<U>) => unknown
): MultipleIfs<[U]>;
```

So here a `MultipleIfs<T>` is an object with an `and()` method that takes another `args`/`cb` pair and produces a `MultipleIfs<[...T, U]>`, where `T` is the same tuple-of-tuples from before, and where `U` is the new element to add at the end, and it also has a `done()` method that returns the final output, whatever that is.

Now inference works well:

```
const result =
  multipleIfs([first, last], (first, last) => null) // okay
    .and([after, before], (after, before) => null) // okay
    .done();

// const result: OutputType<[
//   [number | null | undefined, number | null | undefined], 
//   [Date | null | undefined, Date | null | undefined]
// ]>
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-YfDogjweWMCzCzwCyi45IQCcZKXNOHI9XXe76zs10UN3b3W2Oz4Of3ewOL2Px1frxYpxgZ3O1Bol6Czk6iN2AFRIVPAdPyJmGBSkgPKJMQyQUPwJaXpoMpygqfrxsqtr2rq1bweacZqihgZoVI9Ysl0mgxr6KrIRqeHBtWpHYdauGJg6BFvvoX7dp0wSdJU0BwIgSAAGIYPQkjEAAQvQFgYD0FoEKCViRo4NRIAAsrm+aFksYgSNIshPMCexAtCz4nOcQQEP26hSPwACqyzaWselGccFxXBeOIQusUIvFi1ldheaIYli7l4l4hK+CSPB8DZuhHpR9KMsy-ZcipalzAs0FYoI1a+boH5dJsEA7MlYF8lBAp5ZxoI9H0OLIEMIxjBMUzAXmaWLLZWmrLphnbM5eiuWCwWQs8MI+X5YIBbsQW4h4oU+MSnCRQI1kxTScUMkynIeKpLXqelmg5cmBoQKKjYgZhiHkThlGMY6oYnTWJrkQhFpIddqFJvdoqbvIXo+nRCZBkxeVhhGRR-bGb30TdQN3SmaaioBWYGCyzUzG1xZnc2tbENuWOPa2a1WtS57UDYfBEUg2LSMWu5cPubryNudMM4eRM+CTfZkxTF6vAVRVHV055-gB0DTNy8TgZB-gwULfZEHBZqXf6DGw1IGFK69V3Qx9TGETc54K7RUOA-hNH-Sbqv4aecusoKkSccEQA)